# LESS variables embeded by @import or directly?

Tags: css, styles, less

I have this toughie. I have my LESS variables and mixins setup. Now I would like to learn how better import them. Everywhere I read that add style by imports is bad and should not do this, f.e:

1. http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/
2. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#AvoidCssImport

The arguments are understandable, but how to do this referring of use LESS? Is it better to put all the variables and mixins in the main file or @import in this case is not so bad and check properly. I will be grateful for help. BR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that they refer to CSS imports.
If you use LESS imports and the "compile" the less file you get one single file as the result, not impacting the performance of the browser in the way stated in your linked articles.

So all-in-all, i would say, just make sure your files end in .less and they will be consolidated anyway.

Comment: So but if i do this by script, not server side?

Comment: Quite simply: Don't. Or the other way around: If you are letting the browser parse your LESS files, then you dont worry about performance enough that a few request more or less will make any difference.